# Android item size in layer-list

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I need to set size for item in layer-list. For using as windowBackground in launch activity. I wrote this XML file and Android Studio displays it correctly. But in application the logo always full screen. How to make it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000004"
            android:gradientRadius="1000"
            android:startColor="#1f3371"
            android:type="radial" >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/texture_5"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="77dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found solution, but I expected better way.
Here is final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000004"
            android:gradientRadius="1000"
            android:startColor="#1f3371"
            android:type="radial" >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/texture_5"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:bottom="214dp"
    android:top="214dp"
    android:left="100dp"
    android:right="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    >
</item>
</layer-list>
```

At least it works at xxhdpi and xhdpi without distortion.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from API 23, it is possible to set width and height right within the "item" tag:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/logo" android:width="..." android:height="..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blanco"/>
    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:mipMap="true"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just change `width` and `height`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172899/splashscreen-with-vector-stretched-full-screen/39173958#39173958).
I had to use my vector drawable as the source to a bitmap object:

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_splash"/>
</item>
```