# SplashScreen with Vector stretched full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-vectordrawable

I did my splash screen with this tutorial and it works great:

- https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Basically I set up a splascreen through theme:

```
<style name="ThemeSplash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/drawable_splashcreen</item>
</style>
```

I wanted to put a vector image inside like this: (drawable_splashcreen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_background_splash_screen" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_najdiflet_logo" />
</layer-list>
```

The image will streched through the full screen. On API 23 it works like it should have. But on older devices it just streches. I tried width, height and even messed up with viewports but no success.

Comment: Try set the desired with and height in item tag.

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work on older devices.

Comment: look inside the vector graphics. There is a width and height attribut in there. The vector graphics are rendered int a bitmap of that size before being scaled for display in any particular screen. Problem is: There is no value you can specify in there that means "as large as the screen". So any value for a small screen will look blurry on a tablet despite it starting as a vector graphics.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem now, have you find a solution?

Answer (score 41):

I stumbled upon the same problem.
Unfortunately there does not seem to be a possibility to make the splash screen work with just a vector drawable for pre API 23.

The problem is you can't load VectorDrawableCompat outside of the process, like in this case in your themes android:windowBackground. So what is likely happening here is, that on API 21 the Vector get's converted to a PNG to be compatible. So in the `<layered-list>`the converted PNG is inserted into the `<item>` element, which causes the bitmap to stretch to all edges, because it's missing the `<bitmap>` element.

**So my solution is the following:** Create a `drawable_splashscreen.xml` inside the folder `drawables-v23` which looks like the following for the vector drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splashscreen" android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Then create another `drawable_splashscreen.xml` but inside the regular `drawables` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_splashscreen" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Notice the `<bitmap>` element. So now, when the PNG is used on pre API 23 devices it will be displayed properly and won't be stretched to the whole background.

Unfortunately you also have to provide splash screen as PNG for this to work in the old APIs.

But for every device with API 23+ the vector drawable will be used.

Comment: isnt your code the other way around, the second one belongs in drawable-v23 and the first in drawable as well as drawable-v24. thats how it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

For full screen splash try to use:

```
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
```

> If not resolve maybe the solution is create separated images
>   for each resolution size.

---

**Most common resolutions:**

- Small    = 240 x 320px (ldpi)
- Medium   = 320 x 480px (mdpi)
- Large    = 480 x 800px (hdpi)
- xLarge   = 640 x 960px (xhdpi)

**Portrait Format:**

- ldpi     =  240 x  360px (0.75 x mdpi)
- mdpi     =  320 x  480px (base density)
- hdpi     =  480 x  720px (1.5 x mdpi)
- xhdpi    =  640 x  960px (2 x mdpi)
- xxhdpi   =  960 x 1440px (3 x mdpi)
- xxxhdpi = 1080 x 1920px (4 x mdpi)

**Landscape Format** (inverted portrait format):

- ldpi     =  360 x  240px (0.75 x mdpi)
- mdpi     =  480 x  320px (base density)
- hdpi     =  720 x  480px (1.5 x mdpi)
- xhdpi    =  960 x  640px (2 x mdpi)
- xxhdpi   = 1440 x  960px (3 x mdpi)
- xxxhdpi = 1920 x 1080px (4 x mdpi)

---

**More about you can find here:**

1. https://design.google.com/devices/
2. [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices)
3. http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/

Comment: I want the logo to be the original size, but it just streches through full screen. That is not the desired effect.

Comment: WinterChilly, you can try to create a new image exactly with the resolution of your device and put the logo in the center without changing original size of it. The background of the image could be white or black to serve as a basis for the logo placed in the center. With the image in the correct resolution and the original logo in the center maybe you can get the desired effect. Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

**Edited solution that will make your SplashScreen look great on all APIs including API21 to API23**

First of all read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) article and follow the GOOD way of making a splash screen.

If your logo is distorted or wont fit and you are only targeting APIs24+ you can simply scale down your vector drawable directly in its xml file like so:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:viewportWidth="640"
android:viewportHeight="640"
android:width="240dp"
android:height="240dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M320.96 55.9L477.14 345L161.67 345L320.96 55.9Z"
    android:strokeColor="#292929"
    android:strokeWidth="24" />
</vector>
```

in the code above I am rescaling a drawable I drew on a 640x640 canvas to be 240x240. then i just put it in my splash screen drawable like so and it works great:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque"
android:paddingBottom="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingTop="20dp">

<!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <size android:height="120dp" android:width="120dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/logo_vect"
    android:gravity="center">

</item>
</layer-list>
```

my code is actually only drawing the triangle in the picture at the bottom but here you see what you can achieve with this. Resolution is finally great as opposed to the pixelated edges I was getting when using bitmap. so use a vector drawable by all means (there is a site called vectr that I used to create mine without the hasle of downloading specialized software).

**EDIT in order to make it work also on API21-22-23**

While the solution above works for devices runing API24+ I got really disappointed after installing my app a device running API22. I noticed that the splashscreen was again trying to fill the entire view and looking like shit. After tearing my eyebrows out for half a day I finally brute-forced a solution by sheer willpower.

you need to create a second file named exactly like the splashscreen xml (lets say splash_screen.xml) and place it into 2 folders called drawable-v22 and drawable-v21 that you will create in the res/ folder (in order to see them you have to change your project view from Android to Project). This serves to tell your phone to redirect to files placed in those folders whenever the relevant device runs an API corresponding to the -vXX suffix in the drawable folder, [see this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?hl=de#ApiLevels). place the following code in the Layer-list of the splash_screen.xml file that you create in these folders:

```
<item>
<shape>
    <size android:height="120dp" android:width="120dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
</item>

<!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
<item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:gravity="center"
        android:src="logo_vect"/>

</item>
```

[image: these is how the folders look]

For some reason for these APIs you have to wrap your drawable in a bitmap in order to make it work and jet the final result looks the same. The issue is that you have to use the aproach with the aditional drawable folders as the second version of the splash_screen.xml file will lead to your splash screen not being shown at all on devices running APIs higher than 23. You might also have to place the first version of the splash_screen.xml into drawable-v24 as android defaults to the closest drawable-vXX folder it can find for resources.

[image: my splashscreen]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible to do with vectors, for devices < API 23, since it is not possible to set the attributes android:height and android:width on the drawable.

To implement my splash screen with a centered icon, I had to export the vector of my logo to .png's for each screen size, and embed a bitmap within the layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen_background" />

    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_rasterised" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Ideally I would not like to have any bitmap images at all in my resources, but at least the splash screen is the only place where I have had to use bitmaps.

Comment: android:scaleType is not valid for <bitmap> and probably silently ignored (it can bu used only with ImageView)

Answer (score 0):

Use bitmap and define you image in the src. Set gravity to center

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/color_background_splash_screen"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: splash screen]

Comment: does not work with vector, as vector is not a bitmap

Comment: OP was specific about using vector graphics: "I wanted to put a vector image inside like this"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I found to solve this is by using a vector asset.
This will ensure that the apk size is not big too. If you're not doing this or don't have an svg file for your logo, you should manually change the DP intensities of pictures and add them manually. You may also use plugins that do that automatically for you.

In case you go with the vector file and still end up getting a zoomed image, add in android:top, left right and bottom to get your logo size right.

Answer (score -4):

Dont put your image in window:Background, instead add as android:src for an imageview for the layout of the SplashScreenActivity.

Comment: Don't want to create another activity. See the article here... https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Image/drawable works here but not vector.