# Android drawable appears stretched for API <23 and correctly for API 23 and above

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, drawable, layer-list

I am currently using a list selector for my listview and created it using layer-list. This is my xml code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_arrow"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="36dp"
    android:top="5dp"/>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

When i build the app, it appears fine on api 23 and above.

[image: api 23]

But for api 22 and below, it looks like this:

[image: api 22]

I came across this post [Shape drawable in layer-list rendered incorrectly for APIs below 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410568/shape-drawable-in-layer-list-rendered-incorrectly-for-apis-below-23) and understood that the attributes width and height work only for api 23 and above. So i added the width and height inside the size tag like this :

```
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_arrow"
    android:top="5dp">
    <size android:height="36dp" android:width="18dp"/>
    </item>
```

But the image still appears stretched. What attribute is needed for api 22 and below to make the drawable look uniform for all the versions?

Comment: you can create drawable,  drawable-v21 and drawable-v23 and Edit for each type

Comment: or refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083002/android-item-size-in-layer-list/38608066#38608066

Comment: i already have the xml file for each type, the codes for api 22 is inside v21 folder

Comment: Can you post item_view.xml ?

Comment: Try set   android:layout_width="wrap_content" to item_view of listview

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in the following way :

```
<item android:drawable ="@drawable/menu_arrow"
    android:right="285dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"/>
```

I guess for api < 23 we need to resize the drawable using top,right,bottom values and for api > 23 we can use width and height.