# How to set drawable (PNG) width and height in layer-list for API level below 23?

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

The following xml code works for setting the width and height of image drawables inside items of a `layer-list` for API 23+:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle"><solid android:color="@color/white"/></shape></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="100dp"
        android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_text" android:gravity="center" android:top="50dp"
        android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" />
</layer-list>
```

However, the `android:width` and `android:height` inside `<item>` only works for API levels from 23 and up. Without the explicit width and heigth values the drawables will overflow the screen, and if I use resized PNG images, the quality becomes poor.

I have searched about workarounds on Stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083002/android-item-size-in-layer-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686116/android-drawable-appears-stretched-for-api-23-and-correctly-for-api-23-and-abov), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410568/shape-drawable-in-layer-list-rendered-incorrectly-for-apis-below-23)) but none of the solutions seem to work.

1. Adding `android:top`, `android:bottom`, `android:left`, and `android:right` don't resize/set the height and width of the `drawable`, possibly because they are PNG images and not vector drawables.
2. Adding a `drawable` to a `shape` (and then use the `size` tag) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve your goal. You have to resize your image. Or you can use `android:width` and `android:height` for API level >=23, and `layer-list` with resized image for API level < 23.

Also, you can't use `android:top`, `android:bottom` etc. properties to resize any images (not png nor vector drawable), those properties are used for positioning.

Comment: Hello Garnik, yes, I have already done that: I use android:width and android:height for API levels 23+, and below 23 I use resized images. Thank you for the confirmation.